# Inverted Y axis of custom tile images names

Tags: javascript, leaflet

There is a know problem of Leaflet that when you use a custom tile provider, not with real earth images, set **crs: L.CRS.Simple**, Leaflet queries for images where Y coordinate is inverted in comparison to the math axis. So the first top-right image's location is **1x-1** instead of **1x1**.

In the internet topics about inverting Y axis are rather old, so my question is: nowadays is there a normal short and built-in way to invert queried Y axis?

The only old solutions I've found were rewriting Leaflet internal objects, like extending **L.CRS.Simple**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the [Leaflet tutorial for WMS/TMS](https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html), the canonical way of inverting the Y coordinate for tile coordinates is using `{-y}` instead of `{y}` in the tile URL template. e.g.:

```
var layer = L.tileLayer('http://base_url/tms/1.0.0/tileset/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png');
```

Note, however, that (as of Leaflet 1.3.1) that [only works for maps with a non-infinite coordinate system](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/fb09dd24c4c9e04d003947f95d6584c1651a203b/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L171).

In your case, you might want to get around this by creating your own subclass of `L.TileLayer`. There is a complete guide on the [Leaflet tutorial about extending layers](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html), but the TL;DR version for a tilelayer that shifts its tile coordinates is:

```
L.TileLayer.CustomCoords = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: function(tilecoords) {
        tilecoords.x = tilecoords.x + 4;
        tilecoords.y = tilecoords.y - 8;
        tilecoords.z = tilecoords.z + 1;
        return L.TileLayer.prototype.getTileUrl.call(this, tilecoords);
    }
});

var layer = new L.TileLayer.CustomCoords(....);
```

And the specific case for just inverting the Y coordinate is:

```
L.TileLayer.InvertedY = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: function(tilecoords) {
        tilecoords.y = -tilecoords.y;
        return L.TileLayer.prototype.getTileUrl.call(this, tilecoords);
    }
});

var layer = new L.TileLayer.InvertedY(....);
```

Comment: Thanks! The cleanest solution I've seen so far, and new for me. Maybe you have some info about why such feature, often enough needed by the community, is not a built-in? Something like a "InvertedY" setting for the "TileLayer" object. I've read about coord. systems infinity, extendings, etc, but I'm sure it can be done natively

Comment: The [Leaflet issue tracker](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues) doesn't have any such feature request, therefore I disagree that this is "often enough needed". The closest you'll find is https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4338. Feel free to request it, though (and better if you can suggest an implementation).

Comment: In my case, my tiles are quads so instead of requesting them with z/x/y, I compute a quad to find the tile. Negating the Y axis in this case does not work, and my tiles are incorrectly flipped. Is there a solution for this? Here is my formula : https://jsfiddle.net/a991fjgj/