# Invert Y axis of L:CRS.Simple map on Vue2-Leaflet

Tags: javascript, r, vue.js, leaflet, vue2leaflet

I am developing a map application using L.CRS.Simple of Vue2-Leaflet, and I want to invert the y-axis of my map as explained in the [Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#crs-l-crs-simple). I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319366/inverted-y-axis-of-custom-tile-images-names), and it seems my problem is the same, so my question is: how do I integrate the same [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319366/inverted-y-axis-of-custom-tile-images-names) that inverts the y-axis but using the vue2-leaflet package?

This is my code:

```
<template>
<body>
  <div>
    <li v-for="(message, index) in messageList" :item="message" :key="index">
      {{ message }}
    </li>
  </div>
  <l-map class="map" ref="map" :min-zoom="minZoom" :crs="crs">
    <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
    <!-- <l-image-overlay :url="url" :bounds="bounds" /> -->
    <l-grid-layer class="grid" :tile-component="tileComponent"></l-grid-layer>
    <l-marker v-for="star in stars" :key="star.id" :lat-lng="star">
      <l-icon
        :icon-size="[25, 25]"
        icon-url="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/304/304378.png"
      ></l-icon>
      <!-- <l-icon :icon-size="[32, 37]" icon-url="/images/star.png"></l-icon> -->
      <l-popup class="popup">
        <em class="popup-bold">Name: </em>{{ star.name }}<br>
        <em class="popup-bold">Longitud: </em>{{ star.lng }}<br>
        <em class="popup-bold">Latitud: </em>-{{ star.lat }}<br>
      </l-popup>
    </l-marker>
  </l-map>  
</body>
</template>

<script>
import L from "leaflet";
import { CRS } from "leaflet";
import {
  LMap,
  LTileLayer,
  LMarker,
  LImageOverlay,
  LPopup,
  LPolyline,
  LIcon,
  LGridLayer
} from "vue2-leaflet";

export default {
  name: "Map",
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LMarker,
    LImageOverlay,
    LPopup,
    LPolyline,
    LIcon,
    LGridLayer
  },
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url: "https://wallpaperboat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/high-resolution-black-background-08.jpg",
      bounds: [
        [-2600, -2700],[1000, 3000]
      ],
      minZoom: 0.5,
      crs: L.CRS.Simple,
      stars: [],
      messageList: [],
      tileComponent: {
        name: "tile-component",
        props: {
          coords: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
          }
        },
        template: '<div style="outline:1px solid #38c9d386; height:40rem; width:40rem;"></div>'
      }
    };
  },
  watch: {
    msg: function() {
      this.messageList.push(this.msg);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.map.mapObject.setView([526, -68], 1);

    this.$http
      .get("https://pyet2m3rzl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/outscapebackend")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        const resultArray = [];
        for (let key in data) {
          resultArray.push(data[key]);
        }
        this.stars = resultArray;
      });
  },
  methods: {}
};
</script>

<style scoped>
...
</style>
```

Comment: Do you want to invert the Y axis for the tile display, or for the coordinates? Those are different things.

Comment: As far as I understand, for L.CRS.Simple the Y coordinate is inverted, so the first top-right image's location is 1x-1 instead of 1x1. Therefore, I should only invert the Y axis for the tile display. I also understand that I need to create a subclass for the L.TileLayer, but my problem is that I am not managing to do that using the vue2-leaflet package :( @IvanSanchez

Comment: The axis order in `L.LatLng`s is easting-northing: Y coordinates (latitude) grow larger when going north (on `L.CRS.EPSG3857`) and also grow larger when going *up* (on `L.CRS.Simple`). The [*Y tile coordinate* in default `L.TileLayer`s](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#X_and_Y) goes *south* or *down* but it goes *north/up* in [TMS](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification). Therefore, it's unclear whether you want to invert the Y coordinate in your CRS (so the axis order is easting-southing and "latitude" grows down) or just the *tile* coordinates.

Comment: then yes, I need to invert the Y coordinate in my CRS, so the latitude grows down

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right, you want to invert the Y coordinate of all `L.LatLng`s, and not just the tile coordinates (which is the [TMS](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification) use case), so that Y coordinates grow when going *down*. In other words, if I have something like...

```
L.marker([0,0]).addTo(map).bindPopup('y=0,x=0', {autoClose:false}).openPopup();
L.marker([100,50]).addTo(map).bindPopup('y=100,x=50', {autoClose:false}).openPopup();
```

...the default looks like...

[image: markers with default L.CRS.Simple]

...but you want it to look like...

[image: markers with inverted-Y CRS]

(If the fact that the Y coordinate is listed first in the shorthand form of `L.LatLng`s, re-read the [Leaflet tutorial on L.CRS.Simple](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) where the issue is explained, as well as [*lon lat lon lat lon*](https://macwright.org/lonlat/)).

A bit of explanation about the Leaflet internals: a Leaflet CRS translates `LatLng` coordinates into pixel coordinates. e.g. in the default `L.CRS.EPSG3857`, the screen Y coordinate depends on the cosine of the latitude to get a [traverse cylindrical projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection).

With `L.CRS.Simple` this translation also exists, because of a quirky disparity. For mathematicians, the Y coordinate goes *up* because that's how a [cartesian plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) works:

[image: cartesian coordinate system]

However, for computer programmers, the Y coordinate goes *down* because [that's how *pixels* are indexed](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-gfx-graphics-library/coordinate-system-and-units) on screens (at least, that's been the convention *for decades*):

[image: pixel coordinate system]

In order to get around this quirk, Leaflet implements [affine transformations](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/geometry/Transformation.js) (which take into account the Leaflet quirks for zoom levels), and then [`L.CRS.Simple`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/geo/crs/CRS.Simple.js) uses such an affine transformation to invert the Y coordinate (so `L.CRS.Simple` works like a cartesian plane instead of a pixel plane):

```
L.CRS.Simple = L.Util.extend({}, L.CRS, {
    projection: L.Projection.LonLat,
    transformation: L.Transformation(1, 0, -1, 0),
    /* snip */
```

This is equivalent to specifying an [affine transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) like

```
( 1  0 )
( 0 -1 )
```

So, with this in mind, the answer to your question becomes "you should define a new CRS with a custom affine transformation that maps 1 unit of «latitude» into 1 downwards pixel".

At this point, you should read the [Leaflet tutorial on extending Leaflet classes](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html), but the TL;DR version of that is:

```
var CRSPixel = L.Util.extend(L.CRS.Simple, {
    transformation: new L.Transformation(1,0,1,0)
});
```

Then define the map passing that custom CRS as the map's `crs` option, and everything should work. [Here's a working example with vanilla Leaflet](https://plnkr.co/edit/RtETEQzQfOJdDxu0) (i.e. vue-less)

With this information, you should be able to adapt the technique to your Vue code, taking a bit of care to `import` all the needed Leaflet bits.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It made me understand my problem better. As you said, if I have something like this:

L.marker([0,0]).addTo(map).bindPopup('y=0,x=0', {autoClose:false}).openPopup(); L.marker([100,50]).addTo(map).bindPopup('y=100,x=50', {autoClose:false}).openPopup();

...the default looks like this: [default map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEQk9.png), but I want it to look like this: [ideal map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8oPW.png)

I basically want my default map to rotate 180 degrees, so I think I misunderstood the part where I told you I needed the latitude to go down.