# Leaflet .png image-map with flipped coordinates?

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, imagemap, bounds, pan

i have a 4096x4096px .png that represents 15000x15000m. With this code it will be displayed perfectly the way I want it and I could also determine the pixel positions (0/0 top left corner):

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/leaflet.css"></script>
    <style>
    #image-map {
      width: 1024px;
      height: 1024px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="image-map"></div>

    <script src="scripts/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Using leaflet.js to pan and zoom a big image.
    // See also: http://kempe.net/blog/2014/06/14/leaflet-pan-zoom-image.html

    // create the slippy map
    var map = L.map('image-map', {
      minZoom: -1,
      maxZoom: 2,
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: -1,
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    });

    // dimensions of the image
    var w = 4096,
        h = 4096,
        url = 'images/Bild.png';

    // calculate the edges of the image, in coordinate space
    var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
    var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

    // add the image overlay, 
    // so that it covers the entire map
    L.imageOverlay(url, bounds).addTo(map);

    // tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
    map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    </script>

  </body>
```

But I don't want the pixel position, i want to get coordinates with a mouse click (0-point in the middle of the graphic). The limits are upper left corner + 7500 / + 7500, lower right corner -7500 / -7500 (and +/- lower left, -/+ upper right) I'm a beginner and I have no idea how to do this. Many of the questions here have similar problems, but I couldn't transfer them to my scenario.

Thanks for your help

EDIT: I have now worked my way towards this code. However, this does not take into account the limits of the overlay and the display is not as good in the example above. You can also read in the XY values outside, cause the picture no longer slides back to the map. The coordinates are ok for that - but they should point in the other direction. How can this be solved? I also think I'm making a mistake with crs: L.CRS.Simple, but when I remove it the graphic is only shown as a narrow strip in the map.

```
<html>

  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/leaflet.css">
    
    <style>
    #map {
      width: 1024px;
      height: 1024px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="scripts/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
    
      var map = L.map('map', {
      minZoom: -3,
      maxZoom: 0,
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: -3,
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    });

      url = 'images/Bild.png';

    L.imageOverlay(url, [
     [4096, -4096],
     [-4096, 4096]
    ]).addTo(map);

    var popup = L.popup();
map.on("click", function(e) {
  popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent('<p>Lng (x): '+e.latlng.lng+'  /  Lat (y):  '+e.latlng.lat+'</p>')
    .openOn(map);
});


</script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suspect this is somehow a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305306/invert-y-axis-of-lcrs-simple-map-on-vue2-leaflet

Comment: I've been looking for something like this without success - it looks promising. many thanks