# Vue Leaflet, Custom Map and Coordinates

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I found out Leaflet and its Vue implementation and wanted to do a small project working around its Vue implementation using custom map tiles and coordinate system.

I must say, I have absolutely no experience with such projects before. Since this is a custom map, I used `CRS.Simple`. Unfortunately the X, Y with 0, 0 coordinates starts at the top left corner of the map rather than bottom left and the map stays actually below it.

Is there any way to position 0, 0 at the bottom left of the map rather than on top left?

```
<template>
  <l-map
    ref="map"
    v-model="zoom"
    v-model:zoom="zoom"
    v-model:maxZoom="maxZoom"
    v-model:minZoom="minZoom"
    :center="[0, 0]"
    :crs="crs"
  >
    <l-tile-layer url="https://localhost:3000/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
    <l-marker :lat-lng="[1000, 500]" />
    <l-marker :lat-lng="[0, 0]" />
  </l-map>

</template>
<script>
import {
  LMap,
  LTileLayer,
  LMarker,
} from '@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import { CRS } from 'leaflet';

export default {
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LMarker,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 2,
      minZoom: 2,
      maxZoom: 8,
      center: [0, 0],
      crs: CRS.Simple,
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you share some code that you've try. It will help others to answer your question. 

Comment: Possibly related to / duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305306/

Comment: @Patfreeze I added the sample code.

Comment: @IvanSanchez it didn't actually help.

Comment: And this link? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274666

Comment: @Patfreeze it actually looks exactly the same. Difference is lat is now `-` instead of `+` value but 0, 0 still is at the top left corner.