# Leaflet CRS.Simple + Y-axis inversion results in tileLayer centered distribution

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am attempting to display a videogame's map in leaflet. It's origin should be in the bottom left, and I would like to use pixel coordinates for the placement of markers and other POI. The tiles I have are organized with respect to the bottom left origin, so I have used an inverted y-axis and `CRS.Simple`, following the [Leaflet Non-geographic maps tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html).

First I modify `CRS.Simple` to have `infinite: true` to enable the y-axis inversion. Then I declare the map, using the modified CRS. I set the bounds to be from (0,0) to the size of the image I have broken down into tiles. I then implement the tile layer, matching my file structure to the URL and setting `tms: true` to invert the y-axis, and use `fitBounds` as the tutorial suggests (though this doesn't seem to do anything?)

```
L.CRS.myCRS = L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, {
    infinite: false
});
// Declare map object
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.myCRS,
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3
});

var bounds = [[0,0], [12544, 44568]]

// Reference the tiles
L.tileLayer('0/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    tms: true,
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 11,
}).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

My understanding at this point is that I should be seeing a map tiled correctly whose origin is (0,0)px at the bottom left of the map.

Instead, when I add a marker:

```
var marker = L.marker(map.unproject([0, 0], map.getMaxZoom())).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup('<b>Origin<b>').openPopup();
```

I find that it is indeed on the left, but the map tiles are centered vertically around this point.
[image]

I measured the pixels and verified this to be accurate. I would like the origin to truly sit on the bottom left of the tiles such that a `Point` of (0,0) appears there and all other pixels exist to the right and upward of that point. Where have I gone wrong?

This jsfiddle is a minimum example of my work: https://jsfiddle.net/rd7v4n5c/24/

Comment: Maybe this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62305306/invert-y-axis-of-lcrs-simple-map-on-vue2-leaflet

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I read that one while I was trying to troubleshoot my issue. I could certainly just write a function to do the conversions for me using the information found in the "The Pixel Origin" example:  https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html. But this seems like it shouldn't be necessary. I am currently re-rendering the rasters I found online because the TileLayer also generates random empty tiles without data I provide, to eliminate that as an issue.